# CodeIgniter passes an object to activerecord _where() function, triggers php notice

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

In a CodeIgniter 2 app, when I go through password restore procedure, the code fires a php notice "Illegal offset type". I found out that this happens because it submits entire CI_DB_mysql_driver object to the _where function of active record class, while normally it should just submit an array of database fields (as array keys) and respective values (as array values).

Here is the procedure:

#### 1. function in users model that updates user information

```
function update($data,$where,$value){
    $filter = $this->db->where($where,$value);
    $this->db->update('user',$data,$filter);
}
```

#### 2. functions in DB_active_rec.php that handle 'where' part of the mysql query

```
public function where($key, $value = NULL, $escape = TRUE){
    return $this->_where($key, $value, 'AND ', $escape);
    }

protected function _where($key, $value = NULL, $type = 'AND ', $escape = NULL)
{
    if ( ! is_array($key))
    {
            $newkey = array($key => $value);
            $key = $newkey;
    }

    // If the escape value was not set will will base it on the global setting
    if ( ! is_bool($escape))
    {
        $escape = $this->_protect_identifiers;
    }

    foreach ($key as $k => $v)
    {
        $prefix = (count($this->ar_where) == 0 AND count($this->ar_cache_where) == 0) ? '' : $type;

        if (is_null($v) && ! $this->_has_operator($k))
        {
            // value appears not to have been set, assign the test to IS NULL
            $k .= ' IS NULL';
        }

        if ( ! is_null($v))
        {
            if ($escape === TRUE)
            {
                $k = $this->_protect_identifiers($k, FALSE, $escape);

                $v = ' '.$this->escape($v);
            }

            if ( ! $this->_has_operator($k))
            {
                $k .= ' = ';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $k = $this->_protect_identifiers($k, FALSE, $escape);
        }

        $this->ar_where[] = $prefix.$k.$v;

        if ($this->ar_caching === TRUE)
        {
            $this->ar_cache_where[] = $prefix.$k.$v;
            $this->ar_cache_exists[] = 'where';
        }

    }

    return $this;
}
```

And it returns php notice "Illegal offset type".
The following object appears to be passed as $key argument to _where function:

```
CI_DB_mysql_driver Object
(
[dbdriver] => mysql
[_escape_char] => `
[_like_escape_str] => 
[_like_escape_chr] => 
[delete_hack] => 1
[_count_string] => SELECT COUNT(*) AS 
[_random_keyword] =>  RAND()
[use_set_names] => 
[ar_select] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_distinct] => 
[ar_from] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_join] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_where] => Array
    (
        [0] => `u_email` =  'test@tester.com'
    )

[ar_like] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_groupby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_having] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_keys] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_limit] => 
[ar_offset] => 
[ar_order] => 
[ar_orderby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_set] => Array
    (
        [`u_pass`] => 'Vm4IOQZpBiIFJw=='
    )

[ar_wherein] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_aliased_tables] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_store_array] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_caching] => 
[ar_cache_exists] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_select] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_from] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_join] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_where] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_like] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_groupby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_having] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_orderby] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_set] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_no_escape] => Array
    (
    )

[ar_cache_no_escape] => Array
    (
    )

[username] => root
[password] => temproot
[hostname] => localhost
[database] => oceantailer
[dbprefix] => 
[char_set] => utf8
[dbcollat] => utf8_general_ci
[autoinit] => 1
[swap_pre] => 
[port] => 
[pconnect] => 1
[conn_id] => Resource id #29
[result_id] => Resource id #55
[db_debug] => 1
[benchmark] => 5.8174133300781E-5
[query_count] => 1
[bind_marker] => ?
[save_queries] => 1
[queries] => Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT *
   FROM (`user`)
   WHERE `u_email` =  'test@tester.com'
    )

[query_times] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5.8174133300781E-5
    )

[data_cache] => Array
    (
    )

[trans_enabled] => 1
[trans_strict] => 1
[_trans_depth] => 0
[_trans_status] => 1
[cache_on] => 
[cachedir] => 
[cache_autodel] => 
[CACHE] => 
[_protect_identifiers] => 1
[_reserved_identifiers] => Array
    (
        [0] => *
    )

[stmt_id] => 
[curs_id] => 
[limit_used] => 
[stricton] => 
)
```

How can I prevent this php notice?

Answer (score 0):

## This worked:

#### in 'users' model:

```
function update($data,$where,$value){
    $this->db->where($where,$value);
    $this->db->update('user',$data);
}
```

#### in DB__active_rec.php:

`protected function _where($key, $value = NULL, $type = 'AND ', $escape = NULL) {
        if ( ! is_array($key)) {
            $key = array($key => $value);
        }
        ...`